# Multiple regression model - model selection by R2

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I'm working with the following data set and split it in a training data set and a test data set

```
library(mvdalav)
data(Penta)

set.seed(321)
> idx <- sample(1:30, size = 20, replace = F)
> ptrain <- Penta[idx,]
> ptest <- Penta[-idx,]
```

I'm running a multiple regression model and I want to select the best model by the step function and R2. So I runned the step:

```
>selectAIC = step(lm(log.RAI~.,data = ptrain[,-1]),direction="backward")
> selectAIC$call
lm(formula = log.RAI ~ S1 + P1 + S2 + L2 + S3 + L3 + L4 + P4, 
    data = ptrain[, -1])
```

Now I want to do the same but using the R^2 of the model as the criteria for selection.

How can I do this?

kind regards